# What's the function of "as" in "rainforest as animal habitats"?

Tags: grammar

> More girls than boys raised the idea of rainforest as animal habitats.

If I wrote the sentence, I would use "being", "More girls than boys raised the idea of rainforest being animal habitats. the words coming right after of should be a noun or a gerund, is that right? If putting "as" here, then what's the function of "as" serve? Is it a conjunction?

Comment: The rainforest is _serving as_ a habitat for animals.

Comment: This doesn't help with understanding the grammar, but I'd paraphrase as: 'More girls than boys raised the idea of rainforest being seen as important in terms of its animal habitats.' Perhaps over-egging.

Answer (score 1):

> *More girls than boys raised the idea of rainforest as (being) animal habitats.*

The grammatical function here of the preposition "as" is **head** of the PP "as (being) animal habitats".

"of rainforest being animal habitats" is also a PP with "of" as head.

Note that prepositions can take a wide range of complements, including noun phrases and clauses.

Answer (score 0):

*As* has many uses. The relevant one here is

> As: used to describe the purpose or quality of someone or something:
>
> She works as a waitress.
>
> It could be used as evidence against him.
>
> The news came as quite a shock to us.
>
> I meant it as a joke.
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)

Applying this definition and examples to your text gives us the idea of describing *animal habitat* to be one of the uses or purposes of *rainforest*.